# Using GDAL Virtual I/O (/vsicurl) when Adding a Geoserver Store

Tags: geoserver, gdal

I was under the impression that configuring Geoserver with the GDAL plugin would allow me to utilize GDAL's virtual I/O prefix for accessing data stores in a zip file, s3, etc. using /vsicurl/ or /vsis3/.

Having gone through the installation of GDAL and geoserver, I am able to use gdalinfo with the vsi prefix to successfully retrieve information about a file hosted in cloud, but when attempting to do this by adding a data store, I'm pretty sure Geoserver thinks this is just a file.

Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

I see no mention of this on the [GeoServer manual page](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/gdal.html) which lists:

> The following image formats can be read by GeoServer using GDAL:
>
> - DTED, Military Elevation Data (.dt0, .dt1, .dt2): http://www.gdal.org/frmt_dted.html
> - EHdr, ESRI .hdr Labelled: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#EHdr
> - ENVI, ENVI .hdr Labelled Raster: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#ENVI
> - HFA, Erdas Imagine (.img): http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hfa.html
> - JP2MrSID, JPEG2000 (.jp2, .j2k): http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2mrsid.html
> - MrSID, Multi-resolution Seamless Image Database: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_mrsid.html
> - NITF: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_nitf.html
> - ECW, ERDAS Compressed Wavelets (.ecw): http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html
> - JP2ECW, JPEG2000 (.jp2, .j2k): http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2ecw.html
> - AIG, Arc/Info Binary Grid: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_various.html#AIG
> - JP2KAK, JPEG2000 (.jp2, .j2k): http://www.gdal.org/frmt_jp2kak.html

Comment: Curious if no way to "cheat" by mounting a volume from remote resource? Seems possible, at least for s3 (keyword s3fs in a search engine).

Comment: Right, those are image formats that Geoserver supports with the GDAL plugin. I would still be reading these formats but through the virtual filesystem /vsi prefix. Most likely I will have to make changes to geoserver or maybe imageio-ext source to route this URI through GDAL, since it seems Geoserver doesn't like anything other than a file://